# Setting a virtual property of model in repository

Tags: mysql, model, typo3, repository, extbase

I'ver created an extension for Typo3 to do a radial search for retailers. The user can search for a location and it shows every retailer near that location in a radius from 10 to 50km. Now I want to show the distance of each retailer to the location. Therefore I set up a property in my domain model:

```
/**
 * distance
 *
 * @var float
 */
protected $distance = '';

/**
 * Returns the distance
 *
 * @return float distance
 */
public function getDistance() {
    return $this->distance;
}

/**
 * Sets the distance
 *
 * @param string $distance
 * @return void
 */
public function setDistance($distance) {
    $this->distance = $distance;
}
```

The distance is calculated in the repository like this:

```
$query->statement('SELECT uid,pid,name,address,city, (6371 * acos(cos(radians( '.$lat.' )) * cos(radians( lat )) * cos(radians( lng ) - radians( '.$lng.' )) + sin(radians( '.$lat.' )) * sin(radians( lat )))) AS distance FROM tx_abcretailer_domain_model_retailer HAVING distance <= '.$distance.' ORDER BY distance ASC');
return $query->execute();
```

And then I want to show it in my fluid template like this:

```
<f:for each="{retailers}" as="retailer">
    <tr>
        <td class="label">{retailer.name}</td>
        <td>{retailer.address}</td>
        <td>{retailer.zipcode} {retailer.city}</td>
        <td>{retailer.distance} km</td>
    </tr>
</f:for>
```

But this does not work and I'm a bit lost on how to get the property working and show the distance to the user.

**EDIT:**
Here's also the controller action:

```
public function searchAction(){
    $arguments  = $this->request->getArguments();

    $context = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Context\Context::class);
    $this->view->assign("lang", $context->getPropertyFromAspect('language', 'id'));
    
    $retailers = $this->retailerRepository->search($arguments);

    $this->view->assign('retailers', $retailers);
    $this->view->assign('arguments', $arguments['searchRetailer']);
}
```

Comment: do you have a controller? Where is this query executed?

Comment: That should work. Since `distance` is float, maybe Extbase is just picky that your setter declares a `string`? (clear system caches after changing that phpdoc...)

Comment: I second what @JonasEberle said. Had to do exactly what you just tried and the only difference I can see is that the setter/getters are float all the way, including the default value definition of the property (which should be 0.0 for float and not '')

Comment: Unfortunately setting the default value definition of the property to 0.0 and clearing the system cache didn't work either.

Comment: Simplified version of the query I used:
`SELECT
   *,
   (
      ACOS( 
    SIN( RADIANS(latitude_field) ) * SIN( RADIANS(47.5535997) ) 
  + COS( RADIANS(latitude_flied) ) * COS( RADIANS(47.5535997)) * COS(RADIANS(longitude_field) 
  - RADIANS(8.8987541) ) ) * 6371
   ) AS radius 
FROM
   table_locations  
ORDER BY
   radius` only difference I see is your having construct. Which shouldn't really cause a problem.

Comment: Also my TCA looks like this `        'radius' => [
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'passthrough',
            ],
        ],` And there is no SQL field in the database table. The whole field is purely virtual

Comment: @Waldgeist That's it. It was the TCA. I totally forgot that. Thank so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the feedback by Patricks, let's construct a little guide for "future generations", that might stumble on this post.

### How to automap a virtual field of a DB query to a TYPO3 model

1. Add the virtual field to the model with the right type setter/getter
2. Add the field to the TCA as passthrough
3. Don't add the field to the DB table itself
4. In the query add the field with `as <name>`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define it on your Controller: Assuming that the position of the user is changing you do not need a static "current" position, so you will have to set the distance just before the list is rendered.

I guess you are in some kind of a listAction so here is an example:

```
public function listAction() {
   foreach($retailers as $retailer) {
       $retailerDistance = $this->retailerRepository->getRetailerDistance($variable1, $variable2, $variable3)
       $retailer->setDistance(retailerDistance);
   }
}
```